# Slayer key not present after using cheat codes once on a previous level

Tags: doom-eternal

I'm just curios if anybody else experienced this?

Two days ago:

Hurray I bought Doom I start playing.

I'm on level one, I collect everything but and the end I miss one lore page. Instead of fast traveling I accidentally finished the map.
I activate the only cheat I have, infinite lives and run through the map again to get the damn lore page.
I then disable cheat codes in the mission select menu again.

Yesterday:

I click continue campaign

I'm on the second level, everything is fine, I do all the secrets, get to the part where the slayer key is supposed to be but nothing is there. I know that slayer keys are only active with cheats disabled. I do the rest of the map and then exit to the mission select menu to find that the infinite lives cheat code is active *AGAIN*. Nevermind I disable it again and do the entire map again just to get the slayer key and gate. After this I make abso-fucking-lutely sure that cheats are disabled.

Today:

I click continue campaign:

I start playing on level 3. I play on ultra violence. It's hard, I die several times. At least I know the infinite lives cheat is disabled for sure. I get to the slayer gate and the key is missing. After finishing the map again I go to the mission select screen to find that infinite lives cheat is active.

What am I doing wrong? Is this a known bug? Am I an idiot?

**Update**

After this level all is back to normal it seems. This was the only major issue so far with the game. (Replaying level 1 and loading from checkpoint certainly has it's problems but that is only for that level :)) Otherwise the game is excellent and (if I ignore this issue) certainly a bit better than the original one

Comment: There's quite a few deleted answers here with users experiencing similar or identical problems to your own, so it seems that there might be quite a few bugs around cheat codes.

Comment: Thanks. Why deleted though? Yeah I saw some other comments regarding missing slayer keys so I assume these will be fixed. Ignoring this bug the game is excellent tbh.

Comment: They were deleted, since they weren't answers. Just users essentially saying "I've got the same problem!".

Comment: Oh... I didn't notice any of these replies. I usually get a notification or something

Comment: If the post is deleted, then I believe your notification will be removed from your inbox. Most of them will removed fairly quickly, so they were probably deleted before you saw the notification.

Answer (score 2):

Slayer Gates & Keys are not available to you if you use cheat codes.  This is a normal function of the game itself (and mentioned in the Codex I believe - I saw this information in game at least).

Having the cheat codes remain active, even after you have disabled them sounds like a bug.  There have been a few bugs reported that relate to the cheat codes, so hopefully this will all be patched and fixed soon.